# Change Cash Function Optimization - Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, oop, object

Today I come to your aid in favor of optimizing some code!

I was asked to solve a problem on a test a few weeks ago, and came up with this non-optimal solution since I'm beggining to learn Javascript.

I wonder if there's a way (of course there is) to make this better.

Here's the situation:

"I am a particular kind person who has an infinite ammount of $2, $5 and $10 dollar bills, and I'm willing to change cash for anyone who wants it, BUT in the most efficient way, with the minimum ammount of bills."

Since I had to return an object with the number of bills (or null in case of less than $2), I gave the following solution:

```
function giveChange(change){    
var two = 0;
var five = 0;
var ten = 0;
var changeToGo = change;

while(changeToGo >= 11){
    changeToGo -=10;
    ten+=1;
}

while(changeToGo >=7 && changeToGo <=11){
    changeToGo-=5;
    five+=1;
}

while(changeToGo >=2 && changeToGo <=6 ){
    if(changeToGo == 5){
        changeToGo -=5;
        five+=1;
}
    else{
        changeToGo -= 2;
        two+=1;
    }
}

if (change < 2){
    return null;
}

return {
    two: two,
    five: five,
    ten: ten
};
}
```

I think there must be a clever and more elegant solution (probably with mod% or something), but that monstrosity was what I was able to pull off at the time hahaha.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Sorry, I had to rewrite the function as I remembered on the fly, the function worked on the test version, this was just a typo. (Editing right now).

Comment: Most developers would probbaly use the modulus operator. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()

Comment: Well. Optimal (and general) solutions are related to partitions, which are a difficult problem. I’ll try to provide an elegant solution in the next few days. This comment is for me to remember

Comment: How can we use the modulus on this case? Also, I was asking about efficiency because in REALLY LARGE numbers, I ended up using a lot of memory and that was not permitted on the test, and I had to do a very ugly trick to take care of that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Edit: Removed he initial answer, as it was based on a misconception about the requirements.*

Ok, then let's turn that around, first let's determine how many $2 bills I'll have to hand out to get to a number that's divisible by $5 bills. So for now I only care about the rests < $5 for to calculate the $2 bills.

The generic idea is, If I have a value where `change%5` is 2, like $12 or $17 or $22, ... I hand out one $2 bill and I can divide the rest by 5.

For values like $14, $19, ... it's two $2 bills, for $11, $16, ... I subtract $6, and for $13, $18, ... it's $8

With that I have a static table of how many $2 bills I'd have to hand out, for every `change % 5`; no loops or so needed, just a simple lookup.

```
function giveChange(change){
  const two = change < 4? change>>1: [0,3,1,4,2][Math.floor(change) % 5],
    rest = change - two*2;

  return { 
    two,
    five: Math.floor((rest%10)/5), 
    ten: Math.floor(rest/10), 
  };
}
```

---

> Care to explain again what this does? "change>>1" and "[0,3,1,4,2][Math.floor(change) % 5];" ?

`change >> 1` is here just a shorthand for `Math.floor(change/2)` and deals mostly with the special cases `giveChange(1)` and `giveChange(3)`; They are not interchangable, but for the range `0..4` (where I use it) they produce the same result.

```
let two = [0,3,1,4,2][change % 5];

//does 
let two;
if(change%5 === 0) two = 0;
if(change%5 === 1) two = 3;
if(change%5 === 2) two = 1;
if(change%5 === 3) two = 4;
if(change%5 === 4) two = 2;
```

And `Math.floor(change) % 5` is just in case that you'll use this with floats, like `giveChange(25.90)`

But maybe an example explains it better

```js
for(let change=4; change<50; ++change){
  let two = [0,3,1,4,2][change%5];
  console.log("change: %i, two: %i, rest: %i", change, two, change - two*2);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important}
```

you see how `two` always always has the same 5 values in the same order, and how the rest now is divisible by 5 and or 10.

That's what this code does, it looks up the Array `[0,3,1,4,2]`, how many $2 bills it needs use for any given `change`, so that the rest is divisible by 5.

Comment: Using the floor method, we end up in the problem where we rob $1 of the customer.

Comment: @Platiplus Yes, but weren't values < $2 ignored?

Comment: They are ignored if you're trying to change $1 alone, because that wouldn't be possible, but if you can achieve the result by changing with other bills, they can't be ignored.

Comment: @Platiplus, added a second code that fixes that; without loops or so. Plus the explanation

Comment: Dude, that's insane! Care to explain again what this does? "change>>1" and "[0,3,1,4,2][Math.floor(change) % 5];" ? Remembering that I'm a REAL beginner at this.

Comment: You're my Hero Thomas. I thought it was so beautiful that I took time to explain it to my father. Not a joke. Thank you so much for the input and explanations.

Answer (score 2):

You could take a combination algorithm and return the denominators in an array

```js
function combine(array, sum) {

    function c(left, right, sum) {
        if (!sum) {
            result = right;
            return true;
        }
        return left.some(function (a, i, aa) {
            return a <= sum && c(aa.slice(i + (a > sum - a)), right.concat(a), sum - a);
        });
    }

    var result = [];
    c(array.sort(function (a, b) { return b - a; }), [], sum);
    return result;
}

function giveChange(change) {
    return combine([10, 5, 2], change);
}

console.log(giveChange(7));
console.log(giveChange(13));
console.log(giveChange(23));
```

Comment: Though I kinda got lost on the syntax and this is very efficient, it doesn't solve the problem because I'm not giving back the correct change, on the cases above, when we try to return $13 or $23, we end up losing $1 in the process. The most efficient and correct way to return $13 would be [0,1,4]. Also, I have to return those values inside of an object with the two, five, ten properties.

Comment: Indeed it works. If I understand well, you build all possible combinations that give the correct amount and you sort them to select the shortest?

Comment: The advantage is that you can use it with any set of bills.

Comment: That's insanely clever, but I gotta admit I'm really lost.

Answer (score 2):

The idea: when the amount is odd, add a five dollar bill. Then add two dollar bills until the remaining amount is a multiple of ten.

```js
function giveChange(amount) {
    var ch = { two:0, five:0, ten:0 };

    if ( amount < 2 || amount == 3 ) return;

    if ( amount % 2 ) {
        amount -= 5;
        ch.five = 1;
    }   
    
    while ( amount % 10 ) {
        amount -= 2;
        ch.two ++;
    }

    ch.ten = amount/10;

    return ch;
}

console.log(giveChange(12));
console.log(giveChange(27));
console.log(giveChange(33));
```

You can also skip the while loop if you use `Math.floor`:

```js
function giveChange(amount) {
    var ch = { two:0, five:0, ten:0 };

    if ( amount < 2 || amount == 3 ) return;

    if ( amount % 2 ) {
        amount -= 5;
        ch.five ++;
    }
  
    ch.ten = Math.floor(amount/10);

    ch.two = (amount % 10)/2;

    return ch;
}

console.log(giveChange(12));
console.log(giveChange(27));
console.log(giveChange(33));
```

Comment: That was it, I ran the tests on huge numbers and It went smoothly, spot on!!! I suppose that is as simple as it gets, right?

Comment: @Platiplus: I suppose too. Note that the while loop makes 4 turns max.

Comment: Yeah, I was asking more like in a less number of lines fashion. But damn, that's pretty much what I needed at the time.

Comment: @Platiplus: you don't even need this while loop, see my edit.

Comment: No idea why this was downvoted. Your code worked perfectly and is the answer to a question on the codingame.com JavaScript assessment. Cheers!

Comment: @HalfWebDev: What part you don't understand?

Answer (score 1):

here is my Solution, tested it and works fine

```
function caisse(cash){
two =0;
five =0;
ten = 0;

if (cash>10){
rendu = cash%10;
ten = Math.floor(cash/10);
}
if (rendu%2===0){
  two = rendu/2
}
  if (rendu%2==1 && rendu>=5)
{
  five = 1
two = (rendu-5)/2; 
}

  else if (rendu%2==1 && rendu<5){
    two=Math.floor(rendu/2);
}
return {"two :": two, "five :": five, "ten : ": ten};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested this code and it worked!

```
function caisse(cash){
var two =0,five=0,ten =0;
if(cash==1||cash==3){
return console.log("impossible")
}else {
if(cash>9) {ten=(cash-cash%10)/10;
cash=cash%10;};
switch (cash){
case 1 :ten-=1;five=1;two=3;
break;
case 2 : two=1;
break;
case 3 : ten-=1;five=1;two=4;
break;
case 4 :two=2;
break;
case 5: five=1;
break;
case 6: two=3;
break;
case 7: five=1;two=3;
break;
case 8: two=4;
break;
case 9: five=1; two=2;
 };
return{
 two:two,
 five:five,
ten:ten,
};
  }
}
console.log(caisse(50))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).